# Storing ZipFile Objects into the Django database

Tags: python, django, zip

The problem I have is quite uncommon I think, because I didn't seem to be able to find an answer on here or on Google.
I have several pictures stored in my database and in order to serve these, I want to zip them, store the ZipFile created in the database which has an AmazonS3 storage as a backend. On more thing, all these operations are done in a background task managed by Celery. Now... Here is the code I wrote :

```
zipname = "{}.zip".format(reporting.title)

with ZipFile(zipname, 'w') as zf:
    # Here is the zipfile generation. It quite doesn't matter anyway since this works fine.
    reporting = Reporting.objects.get(pk=reporting_id)
    reporting.pictures_archive = zf
    reporting.save()
```

I got the error : `*** AttributeError: 'ZipFile' object has no attribute '_committed'`
So I tried to cast the zipfile into a Django File this way : `zf = File(zf)` but it returns an empty object.

Can anyone help me with that ? I'm kind of stuck...

Comment: I don't understand why you want to store the files in the db. Why not store them directly in S3 and serve them from there?

Comment: It's a FileField with the s3 storage. So when I save my model, the updated file is updated on the s3. That's an amazing process. By the way I found the solution right after I posted my question. It kind of happen all the time recently -_-

Comment: @Depado If you have found a solution you *ought* to answer the question yourself (yes, answering your question is okay). The only limitation is that you have to wait 24 hours before accepting it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was kind of not as complicated as I thought. (Which could explain why no one asked that question all over the internet I guess)
Using Python 3.3, your strings are unicode and you mainly work with unicode objects. File needs bytes data to work correctly so here is the solution :

```
zipname = "{}.zip".format(reporting.id, reporting.title)

with ZipFile(zipname, 'w') as zf:
    # Generating the ZIP ! 

reporting = Reporting.objects.get(pk=reporting_id)
reporting.pictures_archive.delete()
reporting.pictures_archive = File(open(zipname, "rb"))
reporting.save()
```